# Type mismatch convert char[] to an object

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, type-conversion

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but this problem seems absolutely stupid.

```
private static void method501(char ac[])
{
    char ac1[] = ac.clone();
}
```

My problem is that the `char ac1[] = ac.clone();` is throwing a **type mismatch error** in eclipse telling me that I can't convert a char array to an Object?

Any reason why this is? It was **not** giving me the same error on the **newest version** of eclipse so wondering if it's just this **older version** is giving me the problem.

Comment: If you show the output of the error, the others can help better.

Comment: Sure it's not the other way round, i.e. Object to char[]

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to char[] yeah its the other way

Comment: That code compiles fine on my machine. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: A type cast will fix it: `char ac1[] = (char[])ac.clone();`

Comment: The code compiles and runs here too

Comment: The code compile on my machine, with Java 8. What is you version of java ?

Comment: Probably it then, was wondering if I needed to update some things, I will do that!

Comment: Check which version of Java you're targeting. It's possible that some very old version of the JLS didn't specify that `clone()` returned `T[]` for an array with element type `T`...

Comment: `clone()` of an array will always create an array of the same type, so code will not throw that exception. Javadoc of [`clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--) says: *Note that all arrays are considered to implement the interface Cloneable and that the return type of the clone method of an array type T[] is T[] where T is any reference or primitive type.*

Comment: could you try what I mentioned? just to give me a lead, not as solution. System.arraycopy(ac, 0, ac1, 0, ac.lenth);

Comment: It's because my java version is outdated. Kind of expected as much just did not want to update it on this machine particularly bad. Typecasting obviously would work but I'm not doing that when I can just update to a better version. Interesting though that they were not explicit in earlier versions of java regarding the clone method.

Comment: @AndrewG: Do you really mean you're using Java 1.4? That's very *very* old. It should be absolutely fine in Java 1.5+.

Comment: No, I was using 1.3. Come on dude, I go hard.

Comment: @DamianLattenero: What would that demonstrate? What lead would it give? It would certainly work, but it would give no information about this particular issue, as far as I can see...

Comment: @JonSkeet well, if that works, and the one in the question doesn't... it's a lead... why would one work and the other doesnt? Two ways of doing the same, you got my point? well.. doent' matter anymore, he has his answer yet I think

Comment: It's a lead to a *workaround*, but it isn't a lead to the question of *why* it isn't working for the OP. A simpler workaround would be to just cast to `char[]`, as that would have worked even in Java 1.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens in Eclipse if you've got your compiler settings to target very old source compatibility.

With a compatibility level of 1.5 or above, it's fine - but if you set the source compatibility level to 1.3 or 1.4, you'll get this error, as early versions of the Java Language Specification *didn't* specify that `T[].clone()` returns `T[]`.

Text from JLS 1.0 section 10.7:

> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> - [...]
> - The public method `clone`, which overrides the method of the same name in class `Object` and throws no checked exceptions

The equivalent text from the Java 8 JLS:

> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> - [...]
> - The public method `clone`, which overrides the method of the same name in class `Object` and throws no checked exceptions. The return type of the clone method of an array type `T[]` is `T[]`.

Go into the project properties and check whether it's using the default settings or project-specific settings, and fix the appropriate settings (either the project-specific ones or your workspace settings) to use a more up-to-date source compatibility.

I suspect you'll find that with your current settings you won't be able to use generics or other 1.5+ features either.

Comment: Not sure if 1.5 is the earliest because I currently have it targeting 1.5 but idk could just be eclipse being wonky.

Comment: @AndrewG: 1.5 should work fine, and does on my machine - it's only when I target 1.4 that it creates the problem. Try using generics... do they work?

Comment: I think it was because I did not restart eclipse after targeting 1.5. However I'm updating regardless because I ought to.

Comment: What an archaeology work ! I started from 1.8 to 1.6. I didn't have the courage to goes on :)